# My background-image does not show up on my website

Tags: html, css, background-image

I want to set a `background-image`, but it doesn't show up on my site. I have tried to set `display: block;` but that didn't work.

```
body {
    background-image: url("images/other/background.png");
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: The syntax is correct but it seems like your path in url() is incorrect. Try double check on it.

Comment: When I type the path in my browser I get the image.

Comment: Try the same with inline CSS to see if it works. Check if your path is right. If not you may need to incude a little bit more source code here like the surrounding HTML

Comment: Inline doesn't work as well.

Comment: ```body {
    background-image: url("images/other/background.png");
    margin: 0;
}
nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    font-family: proxima-nova, sans-serif;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #111;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
}
navblokken {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
a.navblok:hover {
    color: #61D9FC;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #F28602;

}
```

Comment: This is my full CSS code

Comment: What is the path to your CSS compared to your image folder?

Comment: @Robert Please check the spelling of the path, or check the path to the image. I copied your code and all works properly even on IE11.

Comment: Path to my css is just css/general.css and path to the image is images/other/background.png. So I think something else is messing around.

Comment: First check the console in the inspector for possible errors. Maybe this tells you that the image can't be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have the wrong path. If your CSS file is inside /css and your image file is inside /image you should use

```css
background-image: url("/images/other/background.png");
```

Comment: Just figured it out, but didn't know the ```../``` Thanks!

Comment: You can go one folder backwards with ```../```you can also go multiple folders backwards with ```../../../images```

Comment: *relative* pathing is not a good idea, avoid the dot-dot such as `../images/` and instead use *absolute* pathing from the base domain **always** starting the URL with a slash such as `/images/`.